# "last active" or "recent activity"

Tags: web, language

There is a table of company records in our application which displays the timestamp of the last successful login. We assume that this is the last known timestamp when a user (who belongs to a company presented in a table row) was active within that company. So we named this column "Last active".

But there is a discussion taken place whether it should be named "Recent activity" or "Last active" or anything else; and which solution is better regarding the UX (in this case user should understand the intention of the column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what the purpose of the tracking is made. If you track the person "Last Seen at xx/xx/xx" works better than "Recent Activity".